# Install Ubuntu with Windows 8 on Separate partition

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu with windows8 -dual boot, But I want to install Ubuntu on separate partition, like my windows 8 installed on C drive and i want to install Ubuntu on D drive. Tell me the installation steps.

Answer (score 0):

In most computers these days the D drive is the RECOVERY drive which allows you to return your Windows machine to factory specs. You need to check first before you do anything else.
If the D drive is NOT a recovery drive, then all you need to do is to insert the Ubuntu Live CD or USB stick, boot from it (consult the documentation for your computer on how to do that) and choose to install on the D drive. It's as simple as that.